# How to get https.request file upload to work?

Tags: node.js

This is driving me nuts.

Here is the code:

```js
uploadChunk: function(token, releaseParams, artifactParams, uploadParams, blockNumber, length, fileStream) {
    const URL = `${releaseParams.upload_domain}/upload/upload_chunk/${releaseParams.package_asset_id}?token=${releaseParams.url_encoded_token}&block_number=${blockNumber.toString()}`;
    console.log("Calling URL: " + URL);
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-API-Token': token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'accept': 'application/json'
            //'Content-Length': 15023
        },
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.request(URL, options, res => {
            let rawData = '';

            res.on('data', chunk => {
                rawData += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                try {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(rawData));
                    console.log("Request finished.");
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        });

        req.on('error', err => {
            reject(new Error(err.message));
        });

        console.log("Starting chunk upload.");
        fileStream.pipe(req);
        req.end();

    });
}
```

This code is uploading a chunk of a file to Visual Studio App Center using an AWS Lambda function.

If I uncomment the `Content-Length` header, the function will not finish and the Lambda times out after 60 seconds. Originally, I was passing in the correct length of the file chunk, but I was trying to reproduce the "invalid chunk size" message that the `curl` command generates (further down). That did not work.

If I uncomment the  `filestream.pipe(req)` line, I always get the error: `write after end`. The `fileStream` is created like this, and is grabbing just a piece of the file that matches the chunk size:
`let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(artifactParams.path, {start: cSize * (chunk - 1), end: cSize * (chunk - 1) + length - 1});`

Even if I grab a much smaller piece of the file, it still gives the same error every time.

If I comment out both lines, the request completes, and I get a response from the server acting like it accepted the upload although that can't be correct.

If I perform a similar command with `curl` using a fictitious file and content-length, I get a positive response from the server that I did not provide the proper `content-length` (which is correct):

```
curl -X POST "https://file.appcenter.ms/upload/upload_chunk/90ed7aec-b02f-4a49-baeb-b64179b4503b?token=asfas09f8as08fs0f9s0a9f&block_number=1" --data-binary "@test.file" -H "Content-Length: 15023" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
{"error":true,"chunk_num":1,"error_code":"InvalidLength","message":"Invalid chunk length. ChunkNumber: 1 Expected: 4194304 Actual: 15023"}
```

I've confirmed that the `URL` is formed the same in both the function and the curl command.

It's probably not relevant, but I'm following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/uploading) to upload to App Center. All the preliminary http requests work successfully. But, using the same code snippet to upload this file by adding the content-length header and piping the filestream will not work.

On a side note, I think I might also need to URL encode the binary file data, which I think curl does? I'm not sure on that one.

Can someone please help me understand why this is not working as expected?

Comment: (1) their curl example (and yours if you use a split file) needn't explicitly determine the file length and set Content-Length, because `--data*` does that by default (2) but for node.http you _do_ need to supply Content-Length and its value _must_ match the body -- you don't show where `length` of your readstream comes from, but assuming it does not exceed EOF, that is the value to use for CL (3) readstream.pipe does end() so you shouldn't do another (4) no you should NOT urlencode this data; only URLs and bodies _of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded_ should be urlencoded

Comment: ... and curl does so only for `--data-urlencode` which they didn't recommend and you didn't do

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Wow. Thank you. That was exactly it. I had thought about this more before your reply and realized the 'hang' was probably caused because it was waiting for the streamed data which it never got because everytime I tried to pipe the data I got a `write after end` error. The key was to remove the `req.end()` like you suggested. It works now. Wow, I can't thank you enough. Please add an answer and I'll mark it for you. Thanks again.